# In caffe's solver.prototxt, I wonder if I set test_iter*test_batchsize=val_imgs_number, is the Accuracy layer's output the whole val set accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

In caffe's solver.prototxt, I wonder if I set test_iter*test_batchsize=validation_imgs_number, is the Accuracy layer's output the whole validation set accuracy?

Does anyone know this detail?

Thank you very much~

Comment: Look at the duplicate question. You need to set `test_iter` = `val_num_images` / `test batch_size`  to cover the entire validation set each time caffe is in a TEST phase.

Comment: You know every test process will do test_iter times inference, so is the Accuracy layer' screen output the last time's accuracy?

Comment: it's the average of the Accuracy of all the phase

Comment: Can you find the code implementation of this point..

Comment: In accuracy_layer.cu -> Forward_gpu -> top.size() == 1 -> valid_count > 0, there only have: top[0]->mutable_cpu_data()[0] = acc / valid_count;

Comment: but the log display only the average over the entire TEST phase